# I need to add Oracle JDBC driver in Maven local repository

Tags: maven

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/
I tried to do

$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/your/ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle 
    -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=19.3 -Dpackaging=jar
but errors keep showing

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time:  0.068 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-21T20:48:56+01:00

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\Administrateur). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

Comment: Please check again. I run your command on my computer and it works (Apache Maven 3.6.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that "path/to/your/ojdbc8.jar" doesn't not have spaces or special characters or "quote" it.